# Draft forgets title of question

Tags: bug, questions, asking-questions

I was writing a question on *[apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com)*. I saw the little “draft saved”. I went away, then I went back to the page.

I found my draft question, with even the tags, but the title was empty.

Here just now I reproduce the bug.

I have Safari on iOS 7 on an iPad mini.

It would be nice to fix this bug. Thank you !

Comment: With Safari on iOS 8.2, I also encounter the loss of the title.